# reload masonry script on click

Tags: jquery, reload, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to reload the masonry layout after I drag out a div which causes a gap in the layout. Currently by doing a click function.

```
$container = $("#container");
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    gutter: 0
  });
});

$("#click").on('click' ,function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('#container').masonry({
          // options
          itemSelector : '.item',
          gutter: 0
        });
      });
    });
});
```

This does "something" but it doesn't rebuild the layout because it still has gaps in the layout.

http://codepen.io/alucardu/pen/qubzx

Comment: $container.masonry() or msnry.layout() this should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found `msnry = new Masonry( container );` if you put this in a click function you can rebuild the container with the masonry items. I used this after a drop function like this

```
`$( ".vote" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = this;

      if ($(droppedOn).children().length > 0) {
          $(droppedOn).children().detach().prependTo($(lastPlace));
      }

      $(dropped).detach().css({
          top: 0,
          left: 0
      }).prependTo($(droppedOn));
      msnry = new Masonry( container );
    }
  });
})(jQuery);`
```

Comment: Please accept this as the correct answer if it does work for you to close the question :)